# Php, static methods and inheritance.. in search of a valid pattern

Tags: php, inheritance, static, design-patterns

What is the best pattern to achieve this behavior?

I have many methods, say method_1 .. method_N, that can be all parametrized by one parameter, say $k. I would like to have them inside a class as static methods, so of course I could write my ComputationClass like this:

```
class Computation {
    static function method1( $k, $otherParams ) { ... }
    static function method2( $k, $otherParams ) { ... }
    static function method3( $k, $otherParams ) { ... }
}
```

Now, since $k belongs to a specific range of values, say {'dog', 'cat', 'mouse'}, I would like to create many subclasses of Computation, one for every single possible value.

```
class Computation_Dog extends Computation {
    static function method1( $otherParams ) { parent::method1('dog', $otherParams); }
    static function method2( $otherParams ) { parent::method2('dog', $otherParams); }
    static function method3( $otherParams ) { parent::method3('dog', $otherParams); }
}
class Computation_Cat extends Computation { .. }
class Computation_Mouse extends Computation { .. }
```

But this is pretty ugly and makes me renounce to the advantages of inheritance: what happend if I add a method to Computation? have to edit all the subclasses.. 
Then I smartly switched to this:

```
abstract class Computation {
    abstract static function getK();

    static function method1($otherParams) { ... self::getK() .. }
    static function method2($otherParams) { ... self::getK() .. }
    static function method3($otherParams) { ... self::getK() .. }
}

class Computation_Dog extends Computation {
    static function getK() { return 'dog'; }
}
```

Nice try, but it doesn't work because static methods don't seem to remember the inheritance stack, and self::getK() would call Computation::getK() instead of Computation_Dog::getK().

Well.. hoping to be clear enough.. how would you design this behavior?
PS: I really need them as static methods

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would not design this behaviour at all. If you need to call parent::Method1('dog'), that means that the parant apparently knows about calculating dogs. Your Calculating_Dog class is just a stupid class containing shorthands.

And yes, if you add a method to the base class, you'll have to add it to all other classes.

If you would have instances instead of static classes, you could add a propery to the class containing the calculation type. Then, you wouldn't need the long functions. You could just add the shorthand functions to the base class and use the property instead of a parameters.
You can give this class a protected constructor and pass it the right type.

Then you could create descendants that have a constructor without a parameter, which call their parent's constructor with the desired type as a parameter.
Then, make singleton references to these descendants.

That would be a way to get close to what you want. But I'd need to see or hear what you're actually trying to achieve to determine if this is the best solution.

[edit]

You can use __callStatic (from PHP 5.3) to catch static method calls of non existent methods. You can then unshift the extra 'dog' param to the beginning of the attributes and call the Calculate base class. Two ways are demonstrated here:

```
/* METHOD 1 Use __callStatic and make the parent function protected
   to hide them. Else __callStatic won't work. */
class Calculate1
{
    protected static function Method1($type, $param)
    {
        echo "Retrieving call for $type with param $param.";
    }
}

class Calculate_wrapper1 extends Calculate1
{
    static function __callStatic($functionName, $attributes)
    {
        array_unshift($attributes, 'dog');
        var_dump($attributes);
        // using get_parent_class()
        return call_user_func_array(array(get_parent_class(), $functionName), $attributes);
    }
}

Calculate_wrapper1::Method1('String');

/* METHOD 2 Don't inherit the wrapper from Calculate. This way the methods of
   Calculate itself can (must!) be public. */
class Calculate2
{
    public static function Method1($type, $param)
    {
        echo "Retrieving call for $type with param $param.";
    }
}

class Calculate_wrapper2
{
    static function __callStatic($functionName, $attributes)
    {
        array_unshift($attributes, 'dog');
        var_dump($attributes);
        // using the fixed class name
        return call_user_func_array(array('Calculate2', $functionName), $attributes);
    }
}

Calculate_wrapper2::Method1('String');
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, what you say is true.. but, as I specified, I need static methods.. and yes, Calculating_Dog class is just a stupid class containing wrappers.. but this is exactly what I want

Comment: I added a possible solution using the __callStatic magic method. It allows you to redirect all static function calls to functions that don't exist in the class itself. This way, you don't have to copy all function declarations to all wrapper classes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the code, but I think the solution for your problem is using [Late Static Bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

However, if you can be a little more specific about what the methods exactly do, we might be able to give you a better overall solution.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, Late Static Bindings is the answer

Answer (score 0):

From php5.3, you can use Late Static Bindings.Use `static::getK()` instead of `self::getK()`.
[Late Static Bindings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Comment: Thank you very much, Late Static Bindings is exactly what I need